# What is the inverse Laplace transform algorithm that is most accurate given the fewest frequencies considered?

Tags: fourier-transform

Based on your empirical knowledge.

[This paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11075-012-9625-3) suggests a nonlinearly accelerated Fourier series approach, such as the one proposed [here](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/0903022), but I have one constraint: we should be able to express the method as a linear combination of the function $F$ at different frequencies $s$, that is

$f(t) \approx \sum\limits_{i=1}^N w_i^t \, F(s_i^t)$

In this equation I am looking for the most accurate algorithm that requires the lowest $N$.

Comment: Is there anything known about $F$ or $f$? Or we are looking at purely arbitrary $F$?